# I want to add card number in stripe dashboard customer

Tags: php, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I want to add card number while creating Customer in Stripe payment dashboard.The data is coming from payment form via data-stripe.

```
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array("source" => $token,"description" => "$userid"));
```

Answer (score 0):

this is not a great fit for the Stack Overflow format, and it's impossible to diagnose the problem based on what you've shared. I'd recommend contacting Stripe support so someone look at your code in more detail:

https://support.stripe.com/email/login

A complete example of creating a customer from a card number is here:

https://stripe.com/docs/charges#saving-credit-card-details-for-later